# file walking in python

Tags: python

So, I've got a working solution, but it's ugly and seems un-idiomatic. The problem is this:

For a directory tree, where every directory is set up to have:

- 1 `.xc` file
- at least 1 `.x` file
- any number of directories which follow the same format

and nothing else. I'd like to, given the root path and walk the tree applying `xc()` to the contents of `.xc` fies, `x` to the contents to `.x` files, and then doing the same thing to child folders' contents.

Actual code with explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The function [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) recursively walks through a directory tree, returning all file and subdirectory names.

So all you have to do is detect the `.x` and `.xc` extensions from the filenames and apply your functions when they do (untested code follows):

```
import os

for dirpath, dnames, fnames in os.walk("./"):
    for f in fnames:
        if f.endswith(".x"):
            x(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
        elif f.endswith(".xc"):
            xc(os.path.join(dirpath,f))
```

This assumes `x` and `xc` can be called on filenames; alternately you can read the contents first and pass that as a string to the functions.

Comment: Is there any reason to use `.endswith` as oppsed to splitting the file, s albertov did?

Comment: Nope, in fact, `os.path` is probably the more "official" way to do it (but since we're just checking the extension as opposed to extracting the rest of the name, I don't think it matters).

Comment: It's quite a nice solution, but I wouldn't call using os.walk() "non-recursive"!

Comment: For a more modern approach using `pathlib.Path`, use `.glob("**/*")`.

Answer (score 6):

```
import os

# your functions
def xc(contents): ....
def x(contents): ....

# store function references in a dict to dispatch, this is a common python idiom
funcMap = {'.xc': xc, '.x':x}

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(someDir):
    # use os.walk to iterate someDir's contents recursively. No
    # need to implement recursion yourself if stdlib does it for you
    for f in filenames:
        ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
        try:
            function = funcMap[ext]
        except KeyError:
             # no function to process files with extension 'ext', ignore it
             pass
        else:
            abspath = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            with open(abspath) as f:
                function(f.read())
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use `os.path.splitext(f)[1]` as opposed to `.endswith`?

Comment: They don't do the same thing: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith vs. http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good place to use recursion:

```
import os
def process_directory(dirName):
    """Recursively process all .xc and .x files in a parent directory and its
    subdirectories"""
    dirName = os.path.abspath(dirName)
    for f in os.listdir(dirName):
        f = os.path.join(dirName, f)
        baseName, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if ext == '.xc':
            print "Processing [", f, "]"
            xc(f)
        elif ext == '.x':
            print "Processing [", f, "]"
            x(f)
        elif os.path.isdir(f):
            print "\nDescending into directory", f
            process_directory(dirName=os.path.join(dirName, f))
        else:
            print "Not processing", f
```

I hope I haven't missed the point of your question.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a dict to hold an extension -> function mapping:

```
funcMap = {".xc" : xc,
           ".x"  : x}
```

Then you create a recursive function that takes a single directory, gets the list of files n that directory, and determines the extension of each file:

```
def iterateDir(s):

    l = dir.list(s) # Not a real function!

    for entry in l:
        ext = entry.extension() # Not a real function!
```

Now, in this for loop you need to determine if the entry is a file or directory, and perform the right action:

```
        if isdir(entry):
            iterateDir(entry)
        elif ext in funcMap.keys():
            funcMap[ext]()
```

This should work for what you want to do.

**Disclaimer** - can't promise all of this is valid Python. It's mostly psuedocode with Python-like syntax. You should be able to get the idea of what to do from this though.