# How Could Python iterate the directoriy and detect the new files?

Tags: python

How can I iterate all files and **subdirs** in  a Dir,

and can detect new file when put there?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: allfiles = list(os.walk(the_dir))

Comment: please follow the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582550/file-walking-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk). More specifically, try:

```
top="."
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
    for name in files:
        # do something with each file as 'name' (a)
        pass
    for name in dirs:
        # do something with each subdir as 'name' (b)
        pass
    # do something with root (dir path so far)
    # break at any point if necessary
```

To answer the question in your comment, at point (b) in the code, you can handle any subdirectory logic (also you can check to test that you have the right subdirectory to do certain custom logic on), via another function or directly/inline.

Comment: How does it can detect the new files at the Dir or subDir?