# reading all json files and file content in dir and sub dir

Tags: python

I have folder, where json files gets created for every date, and in date for every hours.

I am able to read all the file names by:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".json")):
            print name
```

Root path is `/home/ubuntu/Desktop/temp/06-56-10/27`
In this path there are sub folder for every hour. This subfolder contains json files.
here, `name` prints all json file name. But it does not give entire path of the file, so I could not read it.

Any help apprecited

Comment: `os.walk` returns the root and directory. You have a `root` and `dirs` in your loop already

Comment: @MosesKoledoye:  I could read all file name, but not content of each file. Which I want

Comment: Like here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4582729/5781248 ?

Answer (score 5):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".json")):
            print name
            full_path = os.path.join(root, name)
```

The full path will give you the complete path of the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".json")):
            print os.getcwd()+name
```