# Iterate through all the files inside a folder in Python

Tags: python, iteration

The code below reads an xml file, it then runs a function and as the last step it parses the data into an xlsx file.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml = XMLParser.parse(r'./work.xml')
    xml.recurs_collect(opdata_collector)
    df.to_excel("./output.xlsx")
```

If I want to include a second xml files, I have to basically copy and paste the code and write the name of the new xml file.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        xml = XMLParser.parse(r'./work.xml')
        xml.recurs_collect(opdata_collector)
        xml = XMLParser.parse(r'./work2.xml')
        xml.recurs_collect(opdata_collector)
        df.to_excel("./output.xlsx")
```

I have tried the following but without success

```
directory = 'C:\Users\342\Desktop\num\docs\test'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
        xml.recurs_collect(opdata_collector)
        df.to_excel("./output.xlsx")
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Similar question has been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582550/file-walking-in-python using os.walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```py
directory = 'C:\Users\342\Desktop\num\docs\test'
```

you are directing python to escape U, 3, D, etc. This should result in a syntax error (`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`). There are [many ways](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f) to handle Windows paths in python, but your best bet is going to be [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

I'm not on a windows machine to test this, but I think something like the following should work:

```py
directory = PureWindowsPath('C:/Users/342/Desktop/num/docs/test')
...
```